# Pandas: a column with repeating groups to multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below pandas dataset:

```
set_id
A,B
A,C,E
A
```

Desired result:

```
set_id  set_id_1 set_id_2 set_id_3
A,B      A          B       null
A,C,E    A          C        E
A        A          null     null
```

set_id can have n number of values. Suppose the maximum number of values in set_id is 100, I should have 100 new columns

I tried using multilabel binarizer

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['set_id'] = df['set_id'].str.split(',')
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer  
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer() 
df1=df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['set_id'])                                  ,columns=mlb.classes_,index=df.head(100).index))
```

It will create more than 100K columns as I have more than 100K unique records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df['set_id'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Alternative faster solution with list comprehension:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in df['set_id']])
```

---

```
df1.columns = [f'set_id_{x+1}' for x in df1.columns]
df1 = df.join(df1)

print (df1)
  set_id set_id_1 set_id_2 set_id_3
0    A,B        A        B     None
1  A,C,E        A        C        E
2      A        A     None     None
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.. Is it also possible to fill in None with -1. I'm getting an error ValueError: fill value must be in categories when tried df1.fillna(-1) & df1.fillna('-1')

Comment: It was throwing the same error.. However this worked for col in list(df1.columns):
    df1[col] = df1[col].replace(np.nan, -1). Thanks for the answer